# Help needed to assign the value of an object of array to a variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
int random=0;
int counter=0;
while(counter<25)
{   
    random=arc4random() % 40;
    BOOL flag=[array containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:random] ];
    if(flag)
    {   
        counter--;
    }
    else
    {       
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:random]];
        int p=[array objectAtIndex:counter];    //**line4
        counter++;
    }   
}
```

getting a warning on line 4, not able to assign the value of an object of an array to a variable, please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-objectAtIndex:` returns an object — in your case, an instance of `NSNumber`. To convert it to `int`, use the `-intValue` method. For instance, replace

```
int p=[array objectAtIndex:counter];
```

with

```
int p=[[array objectAtIndex:counter] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do Type casting Nsnumber to int.For converting you can use IntValue metod.for knowing more about Foundation Data Type use apple s documents.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html